# Deleting Game Progress from Facebook?

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-games

On Facebook, you can un-authorize a game you have played, but still many many days later when you open the game - you can authorize it again and continue playing from the exact point you left off.

My question is whether there is any way to delete your game progress without completely deleting your Facebook account?

Comment: That depends on the game itself. Those games are just hosted on Google+. If the game makers don't delete your data even after un-authorizing them, I don't think there is any way to delete them. This is a guess. Will answer if I find any reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Games are just hosted on Google+ / Facebook, and the game progress is saved in the servers of the Game Developers (Eg.: Zynga, Digital Chocolate, Wooga). You cannot delete your Game progress as such.

Even if you revoke the access of the Game from Google+/Facebook, the progress will not be deleted and you will be able to continue playing the game from the same point by opening the game again and granting the game access to your account information once again.

Deactivating Facebook account also does not helps.
In Google+, even if you delete your complete Google+ Profile, your progress does not goes away. You can always recreate the Google+ account with the same GMail address and continue playing from the same point.

Deleting the whole Facebook account (after waiting for the 15 Days "Deactivation" Period) and deleting your whole Google Account (with GMail Address, Contacts, Docs, Calenders everything gone), can alone prevent you from continuing your game again.

Even then, your game progress will be available in the servers of the company, it will just become in-assessible to you for the rest of your life.